# $watch not displaying change with two ui-views

Tags: angularjs

I have `$watch` function where it watches whenever a country is selected, but it's not saving the changed data to the scope.  I had one ui-view, which worked fine, but then I changed the structure and now have two ui-views under same page, both uses the same controller.  Reason for the change was for was to have a clean html page, I could always go back to one ui-view, but it's messy. This is where it started having problems.

here is app.js

```
  $stateProvider
.state('homepage',{
  templateUrl: '/static/partial/home/homeLayout.html',
  controller: 'UploadFileCtrl',

})
.state('homepage.show',{
  url: '/',

  views: {
    querySetup: {
      templateUrl: '/static/partial/home/querySetup.html',

    },
    queryResults: {
      templateUrl: '/static/partial/home/queryResults.html',

    },
  }
})
```

layout.html - ui-views:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 panel-container">


  <div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%;">
    <div ui-view="querySetup" ></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%;">
   <div ui-view="queryResults"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

controller watch:

```
$scope.currentCountries = [
{
  name: 'United States',
  code: 'US'
},
{
  name: 'United Kingdom',
  code: 'GB'
},
{
  name: 'Germany',
  code: 'DE'
},
{
  name: 'France',
  code: 'FR'
},
{
  name: 'China',
  code: 'CN'
},
{
  name: 'Japan',
  code: 'JP'
}
];

$scope.$watch('pickedCountry', function(){

if($scope.pickedCountry != null){
  $scope.countryCode = $scope.pickedCountry.code;
}

});
```

here is querySetup view:

```
<select name="brand" ng-model = "pickedCountry"
        data-ng-options="country as country.name for country in currentCountries">
         <option value="">Select Brand</option>
       </select>
```

I moved the controller out of the `state homepage`, and set for each view under the `state homepage.show`.  This worked fine, but an extra operation is not working.  When selecting a brand, it's supposed to run a calculation and set it in the `queryResults` view.  The results is set to a scope which have to be displayed to `queryResults`.

here is queryResults:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">OSM RESULTS</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<textarea rows="50" cols="100" class="xmlOutput">
  {{ queryResults }}
</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Please help!  Not familiar with Angular $watch, and I think the problem comes when there is two ui-views.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

Found the solution to my problem, so I need to add `$parent` to my model and pass the changed data as a param to my `$watch` function:

html update:

```
<select name="brand" ng-model = "$parent.pickedCountry"
        data-ng-options="country as country.name for country in currentCountries">
         <option value="">Select Brand</option>
       </select>
```

controller update

```
$scope.$watch('pickedCountry', function(data){

if(data != null){
  $scope.countryCode = data.code;
}

});
```

This solved the issue, but still don't quite understand why I needed to add the parent.  Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You have your controller set up to live in homepage, but your templates live in homepage.show which is a child state of homepage. In order to access the variables from that controller you can use $parent (as you've discovered) to access the parent state's scope.

I would recommend restructuring your state definition though so you don't have to deal with that.

```
.state( 'homepage', {
    url: '/homepage',
    views: {
        '':{
            templateUrl:'/static/partial/home/homeLayout.html',
            controller: 'UploadFileCtrl',
            },
        'querySetup@homepage': {
                templateUrl:'/static/partial/home/querySetup.html'
            },
        'queryResults@homepage':{
                templateUrl:'/static/partial/home/queryResults.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I did the recommend structure, and took out the `$parent`, and the `$watch` is not working.  Do I need to leave the `$parent` or do I need to do something else with `$watch`?  For the url, I didn't set to `/homepage`, I need it to be `/`.  Or does it have to be `/homepage' ?

Comment: So it doesn't work the way I thought it did. Each ui-view creates a child scope that doesnt have access to its sibling scope's variables. That leaves you with a couple of options in terms of communication. 1. You can use $scope.$broadcast/$scope.$on to broadcast an event and then listen to it 2. You can use a service for communication or 3.  you can use $parent. If you do decide to use $parent I would recommend not creating a watch as ng-model already implicitly adds a watch. instead set ng-model= $parent.pickedCountry and then in results display it as {{pickedCountry}}

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because child states operate the same as prototypical inheritance (`scope: true`) on directives.

You might consider defining in your controller:

```
$scope.input = {};
$scope.$watch('input.pickedCountry', function(data){
    if(data != null){
        $scope.countryCode = data.code;
    }
});
```

and in the querySetup template:

```
<select name="brand" ng-model = "input.pickedCountry"
    data-ng-options="country as country.name for country in currentCountries">
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
</select>
```